# Change class within menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have gotten great help from the community here and I am reaching out again.
Here is my issue. I have a menu

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li onclick="javascript:changeText(0)"><a id="home" class="current" >Home</a></li>
        <li onclick="javascript:changeText(4)"><a id="company">Company</a></li>
        <li onclick="javascript:changeText(5)"><a id="sub">Subcontracting</a></li>
        <li onclick="javascript:changeText(6)"><a id="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

which calls a js function onclick. This is working properly, what I am trying to do now is update the class="current" to the item clicked. Here is the other js function that I have for that which is not working.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   $(".nav a#home").addClass("current");


   $("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
   });
</script>
```

Any help will be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the css code as well

Comment: you have to use `$("a").each()` or `$("a.current")` instead of just `$("a")`

Comment: it works for me, looks like you have not any jQuery lib included.

Comment: @KingKing Sometimes its the simple s#$t we miss, right. I had jQuery lib loading, but it was at the bottom of the body. I moved the CnhClass function below it, thanks emn178 also. This is why I love it here, quick responses from helpful people. Thanks again all.

Comment: @user3547741 yes, instant reponse is one of the most important things has made the success of SO, while many forums/Q&A sites require us to **F5** to see responses, that's so terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you run script after the dom created?
If not, you can move script to below than the html or use load event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".nav a#home").addClass("current");


   $("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
   });
});
```

Comment: and `$("a.current").removeClass("current");` is better

Comment: agreed with @emn178 but it would be even better if `$("nav a.current").removeClass("current");`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working just fine for me

And I am using your code:

```
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
   });
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKTt8/)

Comment: Like King King mentioned, ensure you are including your library (which you probably are because you mention another function running fine) Also maybe try wrapping your code with `document.ready` like the other answers suggest.

Answer (score -1):

You are removing the class of the first "a" the script can find. You should use this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("current");
}
```

instead of `$("a").removeClass("current");`

You also have to wrap everything in a document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //code

});
```

Comment: `collection.removeClass` will remove the class on **all the items** in the collection, see this http://jsfiddle.net/37jE7/6/ So the OP's code has nothing wrong. We don't need to use `each` here.

Comment: Intresting! Is this a new thing? I know some situations where this didn't work for me.

Comment: @Hauke I don't think it's new, there is a rule to memorize in `jQuery` is when you use a method to modify/add something, it will apply to all the items in collection, but when you use a method to just **get** something on a collection, it will return the value of only the first item (like `attr`). Note that I've just learned jQuery today. (come from .NET world :)

Comment: Good to know, maybe I just mixed this.